# Custom ordering in angularjs list

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of objects something as follows

```
{  
   "Info":[  
      {  
         "Id":1,
         "shortId":"PH",
         "description":"Phone"
      },
      {  
         "Id":2,
         "shortId":"Email",
         "description":"Email"
      },
      {  
         "Id":3,
         "shortId":"M-AD",
         "description":"Mailing Address"
      },
      {  
         "Id":4,
         "shortId":"B-AD",
         "description":"Billing Address"
      },
      {  
         "Id":5,
         "shortId":"OTH",
         "description":"Other"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am ordering them by the ID and displaying on the UI. But now the ordering should be

```
{  
   "Info":[  
      {  
         "Id":2,
         "shortId":"Email",
         "description":"Email"
      },
      {  
         "Id":1,
         "shortId":"PH",
         "description":"Phone"
      },
      {  
         "Id":4,
         "shortId":"B-AD",
         "description":"Billing Address"
      },
      {  
         "Id":3,
         "shortId":"M-AD",
         "description":"Mailing Address"
      },
      {  
         "Id":5,
         "shortId":"OTH",
         "description":"Other"
      }
   ]
}
```

I tried Map but didn't work. Is there any other way I can do that in Angularjs?

Comment: Take a look at the [Angular filter orderBy docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy). You may be able to use a custom comparator if you can define some type of rules around how the items should be ordered (i.e. it's not some arbitrary order that you have defined).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$scope.yourObject = $filter('orderBy')($scope.yourObject, 'id');
```

or in your html :

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in yourObject | orderBy:'id'">{{x}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank for the answer but this will just order by the id in either ascending or descending. I my case the result I am expecting has id's randomly ordered.

Comment: Any way I just created a function to set the sortOrder property in each object based on id and got it. This might not be reliable but solved it for now